# How can i use a rangeByScore get result withing SPRING-DATA-REDIS

Tags: java, spring, nosql, redis, spring-data-redis

I set value using ZADD and get value by ZRANGBYSCORE

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD mytest 1 "one" 2 "two" 3 "three"
(integer) 3
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE mytest 1 3
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "three"
```

then, i set value using SPRING-DATA-REDIS API

```
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add("mytest", "four", 4.0);
```

but, i get value using SPRING-DATA-REDIS API and return value which is not i expect（i expect is [one, two, three, four]）

```
Set<Object> result = redisTemplate.opsForZSet().rangeByScore("mytest", 1.0, 4.0);
System.out.println(result);
[four]
```

and check by redis-cli

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE mytest 1 4
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "three"
```

Why data does not seem to been sync?

Any help appreciated much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
        p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory">
        <property name="valueSerializer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />
        </property>
        <property name="keySerializer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

I find a way,change redisTemplate setting like this will ok~

:)